# Scraping a certain range from a table at a webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from this website, which has a table of game credits for different categories. There are a total of 24 categories that I want to make in to 24 columns. In the example webpage there are 5 (production, design, engineering, and thanks).

It would have been easy if they have different class but they all have the same h3 class: "clean". Different page has different categories, and depending on the page the order changes too. On top of that the information that I need is actually in the next row of the table and in a different class.

So what I figured is if I can make 24 if statements for each categories to find if h3 class:"clean" has any of the categories, then I can scrape the class that I need and else put none. but the problem is all of them share the same class. So I think I can try to use td colspan="5" as a marker for python to let python know when each category ends and starts.

My question is that is there a way to program it to scrape when it encounters td colspan="5" and then stop ??

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request


gameurl = "https://www.mobygames.com/developer/sheet/view/developerId,1"

req = urllib.request.Request(gameurl,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')
infopage = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"col-md-8 col-lg-8"})
core_list =[]

for credits in infopage:
        niceHeaderTitle = credits.find_all("h1", {"class":"niceHeaderTitle"})
        name = niceHeaderTitle[0].text

        Titles = credits.find_all("h3", {"class":"clean"})

        Titles = [title.get_text() for title in Titles]

        if 'Business' in Titles:

            businessinfo = credits.find_all("tr", {"class":"devCreditsHighlight"})
            business = businessinfo[0].get_text(strip=True)


        else:
            business = 'none'


        if 'Production' in Titles:

            productioninfo = credits.find_all("tr", {"class":"devCreditsHighlight"})
            production = productioninfo[0].get_text(strip=True)


        else:
            production = 'none'

        if 'Design' in Titles:

            designinfo = credits.find_all("tr", {"class":"devCreditsHighlight"})
            design = designinfo[0].get_text(strip=True)


        else:
            design = 'none'

        if 'Writers' in Titles:

            writersinfo = credits.find_all("tr", {"class":"devCreditsHighlight"})
            writers = writersinfo[0].get_text(strip=True)


        else:
            writers = 'none'            

        if 'Writers' in Titles:

            writersinfo = credits.find_all("tr", {"class":"devCreditsHighlight"})
            writers = writersinfo[0].get_text(strip=True)


        else:
            writers = 'none'

        if 'Programming/Engineering' in Titles:

            programinfo = credits.find_all("tr", {"class":"devCreditsHighlight"})
            program = programinfo[0].get_text(strip=True)


        else:
            video = 'none' 

        if 'Video/Cinematics' in Titles:

            videoinfo = credits.find_all("tr", {"class":"devCreditsHighlight"})
            video = videoinfo[0].get_text(strip=True)


        else:
            video = 'none'   

        if 'Audio' in Titles:

            Audioinfo = credits.find_all("tr", {"class":"devCreditsHighlight"})
            audio = Audioinfo[0].get_text(strip=True)


        else:
            audio = 'none' 

        if 'Art/Graphics' in Titles:

            artinfo = credits.find_all("tr", {"class":"devCreditsHighlight"})
            art = artinfo[0].get_text(strip=True)


        else:
            art = 'none'             


        if 'Support' in Titles:

            supportinfo = credits.find_all("tr", {"class":"devCreditsHighlight"})
            support = supportinfo[0].get_text(strip=True)


        else:
            support = 'none' 

        if 'Thanks' in Titles:

            thanksinfo = credits.find_all("tr", {"class":"devCreditsHighlight"})
            thanks = thanksinfo[0].get_text(strip=True)


        else:
            thanks = 'none'             

        games=[name,business,production,design,writers,video,audio,art,support,program,thanks]

        core_list.append(games)            

print (core_list)
```

Comment: What is the difference between this and [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60688282/how-do-scrape-from-a-particular-part-of-table-when-the-class-is-all-the-same) ?

Comment: Its essentially the same. I tried the ways previous answers but it didn't work.